# Java regular expression

Tags: java

I would like to convert below if conditon into java regular expression.
The var will be coming as input and it can be any number from -1, 1, -2, 2 upto -20, 20.
I'm looking for a code sample. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
if (var == 1 || var == -1 || var == 2 || var == -2
    || var == 3 || var == -3 || var == 4
    || var == -4 || var == 5 || var == -5
    || var == 10 || var == -10 || var == 11
    || var == -11 || var == 12 || var == -12
    || var == 14 || var == -14 || var == 16
    || var == -16 || var == 17 || var == -17
    || var == 19 || var == -19 || var == 20
    || var == -20){


dosomething;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "regular expression"?  Do you intend to include 0?

Comment: @vjdhama: that will match one of the following characters: `-?012`. Regex does not "do" maths.

Comment: No, 0 is not a valid input

Comment: I guess I'm not doing any math here. I have input coming in as int which can contain any value from -1,-2, upto -20, 1,2..upto 20. My requirement is to peform certain logic if input value is in the given range.

Comment: I think the problem is that your title is very misleading ("regular expression" means something very specific in programming / computer science), and your actual question is so basic that we can't really help.

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers are integers in the range [-20, 20], you can simply do:

```
if (var >= -20 && var <= 20){
   doSomething();
}
```

I don't know why you want to use a regular expression for this. If your input is coming up as a `String` just parse it using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: What about `-2`, -`3` etc.?

Comment: @arshajii Oups sorry. Fixed.

Comment: @Jongware Well there is also not 6,7,8,9 and so on in the example he posted. So i'm not really sure what values he should exclude or not (should we base on the code or the text?). But I hope adding the zero check will be trivial for the OP ;)

Comment: It's mentioned in the description though. I guess the OP is lucky not having to check for a floating pount range: `if (var == 0.000000001 || var == 0.00000002 || ...`

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume var is a String and that you really do want a regular expression for some strange reason.

```
if (var.matches("-?([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)")) {
  dosomething;
}
```

Comment: var is int and it can contain any integer value ranging from -1,-2... upto -20, 1,2... upto 20.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question (via a regex, which is what was asked for), even if it's a bit nonsensical.  Haha

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're describing a disjoint category, not including zero (since I don't see that in your original `if` statement).

If you're looking at a continuous range between [-20, 0) U (0, 20], then this boolean expression will help:

```
if(var != 0 && var >= -20 && var <= 20) {
    // logic
}
```

Regular expressions are best suited to parsing textual expressions, not numeric ranges.